# perl list context of hash refs

Tags: perl, perl-hash

Why does this work? that is line 2

```
DB<1> $a = {'a'=>1}; $b = {'a'=>2, 'b'=>0};
DB<2> $c = ($a, $b);
DB<3> print $c;
  HASH(0x8743e68)
DB<4> print $c->{a},$c->{b};
  20
```

I understand if I carefully use %$a and %$b that perl would know what I meant, but with just bare refs in the list, why does it work?

Or maybe it just looks like it works and I really did something else?

Comment: Oh, beware the 'too simple' test. If I has used $a = {'a'=>1, 'c'=>3); I would have seen the failure.

Comment: Looks like a carefully constructed question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no list context in

```
$c = ($a, $b);
```

Instead, what you are seeing is the [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) in action:

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator.

To see this more clearly, take a look at:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $x = {a => 1};
my $y = {a => 2, b => 0};

my $z = ($x, $y);

print "\$x = $x\t\$y = $y\t\$z = $z\n";

my @z = ($x, $y);
print "@z\n";
```

First, I used [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). Therefore, when I run this script, I get the warning:

> `Useless use of private variable in void context at C:\Temp\t.pl line 7.`

**Always** enable warnings.

Now, the output shows what's happening:

```
$x = HASH(0x39cbc)      $y = HASH(0x39dac)      $z = HASH(0x39dac)
HASH(0x39cbc) HASH(0x39dac)
```

Clearly, `$z` refers to the same anonymous hash as does `$y`. No copying of values was done.

And, `$z[0]` refers to the same anonymous hash as does `$x` and `$z[1]` refers to the same anonymous has as do `$y` and `$z`.

Note that parentheses alone do not create list context. In the case of

```
my @z = ($x, $y);
```

they are necessary because `=` binds more tightly than the comma operator.

```
my @z = $x, $y;
```

would assign `$x` to `$z[0]` and discard `$y` (and emit a warning) whereas

```
my @z = 1 .. 5;
```

would work as expected.

Finally, if you wanted to assign to `$z` a new anonymous hash which contains copies of the anonymous hashes to which both `$x` and `$y` point, you would do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = {a => 1};
my $y = {a => 2, b => 0};

my $z = { %$x, %$y };

print Dumper $z;
```

which would output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 2,
          'b' => 0
        };
```

because hash keys are, by definition, unique. If you want to preserve all values associated with the keys of both hashes, you need to do something slightly more complicated (and use anonymous arrayrefs as values in the "union" hash):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = {a => 1};
my $y = {a => 2, b => 0};

my $z;

push @{ $z->{$_} }, $x->{$_} for keys %$x;
push @{ $z->{$_} }, $y->{$_} for keys %$y;

print Dumper $z;
```

Output:

```
VAR1 = {
         'a' => [
                  1,
                  2
                ],
         'b' => [
                  0
                ]
       };
```

Comment: Yes! Just what I figured, it actually was 'doing' something else.

Comment: thought a comparison would make it clearer.  Feel free to correct/rollback if I messed it up

Comment: @bemace I thought it would be better to clarify that no copies of the underlying anonymous hashes are made.

Comment: To get the result you intended, you could have said `($c) = ($a,$b)`